# RxCamera aspect ratio is strange

Tags: java, android

I made android camera app using RxCamera. But camera screen is narrow.
I can't use standard camera app because I have to customize camera with few features. RxCamera is best for me.
How can I make it like the aspect ratio of a standard camera app on Android phones?
Can anyone help me?

Here is my RxCamera configuration.

```
private void openCamera() {
    int camWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int camHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - getStatusBarHeight();

    RxCameraConfig config = new RxCameraConfig.Builder()
            .useBackCamera()
            .setAutoFocus(true)
            .setPreferPreviewFrameRate(15, 30)
            .setPreferPreviewSize(new Point(camHeight, camWidth), false)
            .setMuteShutterSound(true)
            .setHandleSurfaceEvent(true)
            .build();

    RxCamera.open(this, config).flatMap(new Func1<RxCamera, Observable<RxCamera>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<RxCamera> call(RxCamera rxCamera) {
            return rxCamera.bindTexture(textureView);
        }
    }).flatMap(new Func1<RxCamera, Observable<RxCamera>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<RxCamera> call(RxCamera rxCamera) {
            return rxCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Subscriber<RxCamera>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(final RxCamera rxCamera) {
            camera = rxCamera;
        }
    });
}
```